# Merging multiple json files in a dataframe from the same directory in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge multiple json files (over 1,000) with the same column name and format in the same directory. The file format is somewhat similar to the following:

```
id  text         no_people   location
01  it is this   109         paris
02  and you      80          rome
..  ...          ..          ..
05  this is      98          madrid
```

However, when I try to use the code below I get an empty dataframe. It says `Problem with parsing; users_1388322802692984834.json` Would very much appreciate any suggestion to solve this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
df = pd.DataFrame()
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in tqdm(files):
        if ".json" in file:
            try:
                df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_json(file)], axis=0)
            except ValueError:
                print('Problem with parsing; ' + file)
                continue
```

**EDITS:**
These files were downloaded by using `R`. As a solution, I have now combined all these `json` files in `R` in `.rds` format. However, I cannot open `.rds` format in python using the following code.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('users.rds', "utf-8")
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-9417bd5875d9> in <module>
      4 
      5 readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
----> 6 df = readRDS('users.rds', "utf-8")
      7 df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    197                 kwargs[r_k] = v
    198         return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
--> 199                 .__call__(*args, **kwargs))
    200 
    201 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    124                 new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2rpy(v)
    125         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
--> 126         res = conversion.rpy2py(res)
    127         return res
    128 

~\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    805                             '1 positional argument')
    806 
--> 807         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    808 
    809     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in rpy2py_listvector(obj)
    243 def rpy2py_listvector(obj):
    244     if 'data.frame' in obj.rclass:
--> 245         res = rpy2py(DataFrame(obj))
    246     else:
    247         res = numpy2ri.rpy2py(obj)

~\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    805                             '1 positional argument')
    806 
--> 807         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    808 
    809     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in rpy2py_dataframe(obj)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    805                             '1 positional argument')
    806 
--> 807         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    808 
    809     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in rpy2py_dataframe(obj)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    805                             '1 positional argument')
    806 
--> 807         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    808 
    809     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in rpy2py_dataframe(obj)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    805                             '1 positional argument')
    806 
--> 807         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    808 
    809     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in rpy2py_dataframe(obj)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    252 def rpy2py_dataframe(obj):
    253     items = OrderedDict((k, rpy2py(v) if isinstance(v, Sexp) else v)
--> 254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
    256     res.index = obj.rownames

~\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    805                             '1 positional argument')
    806 
--> 807         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    808 
    809     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in rpy2py_dataframe(obj)
    254                         for k, v in obj.items())
    255     res = PandasDataFrame.from_dict(items)
--> 256     res.index = obj.rownames
    257     return res
    258 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5285         try:
   5286             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 5287             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5288         except AttributeError:
   5289             pass

pandas\_libs\properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    659 
    660     def _set_axis(self, axis, labels) -> None:
--> 661         self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
    662         self._clear_item_cache()
    663 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    170 
    171     def set_axis(self, axis, new_labels):
--> 172         new_labels = ensure_index(new_labels)
    173         old_len = len(self.axes[axis])
    174         new_len = len(new_labels)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in ensure_index(index_like, copy)
   5356             index_like = copy(index_like)
   5357 
-> 5358     return Index(index_like)
   5359 
   5360 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name, tupleize_cols, **kwargs)
    436                     )
    437             # other iterable of some kind
--> 438             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=object)
    439             return Index(subarr, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, name=name, **kwargs)
    440 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype)
    220 
    221     if not (isinstance(values, (list, tuple)) or hasattr(values, "__array__")):
--> 222         values = list(values)
    223     elif isinstance(values, ABCIndexClass):
    224         return values.values

TypeError: 'NULLType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file seem not to be a JSON file but a fixed table width format. Perhaps, you should use [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
df = pd.DataFrame()
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in tqdm(files):
        if ".json" in file:
            try:
                df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_fwf(file)], axis=0)  # <- here
            except ValueError:
                print('Problem with parsing; ' + file)
                continue
```

Code suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
from tqdm import tqdm

data = []
for file in tqdm(pathlib.Path('.').glob('**/*.json')):
    try:
        data.append(pd.read_fwf(file))
    except ValueError:
        print('Problem with parsing; ' + file)

df = pd.concat(data)
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, thanks for the response. I have made some edits, which somewhat differs from the previous problem. But to respond to the code you have suggested, I now get all the data horizontally ordered like this ```0 rows × 11394 columns```.